# Does surreal numbers with bounded birthdays form a field?

Tags: set-theory, ordered-fields, surreal-numbers

For a surreal number $X = \{X_L|X_R\}$, its birthday is defined recursively to be the smallest ordinal bigger than the birthdays of all $x \in X_L \cup X_R$. If $X$ can be written as $\{X_L|X_R\}$ in several way, then the birthday is the minimal of the possible birthdays.

Let $\alpha$ be some uncountable regular cardinal, and consider the set of surreal numbers with birthday less than $\alpha$. Does this set form a field?

For $\alpha = \omega$ this is not the case, since 3 has birthday 3, while $\frac13$ has birthday $\omega$. It seems to me that division is the main obstruction, but my thinking is that on day $\omega$ each number has a reciprocal so perhaps this won't be a problem for uncountable cardinals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific result you are asking about is true and was proved for any uncountable ordinal (irrespective of it being regular or not) by Harry Gonshor in his book *An introduction to the theory of surreal numbers*.

The exact characterization of ordinals $\lambda$ such that the set $\mathbf{No}(\lambda)$ of numbers with birth day $<\lambda$ is a subfield was given by Lou van den Dries and Philip Ehrlich in *Fields of surreal numbers and exponentiation*. Their result is that $\mathbf{No}(\lambda)$ is a subfield if and only if $\lambda$ satisfies $\omega^{\lambda}=\lambda$. Those ordinal numbers are sometimes called $\varepsilon$-numbers, and can also be defined as numbers $\lambda>2$ which are closed under ordinal exponentiation.

In particular, there are many small countable ordinals $\lambda$ for which $\mathbf{No}(\lambda)$ is a field.

Comment: I believe you mean to say "any uncountable cardinal, regular or not". $\omega_1+1$ is an uncountable ordinal that is not an ε-number, and thus No($\omega_1+1$) is not closed under division.